# Oracle universal installer cannot continue installation if the user is root

Tags: kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux and trying to install oracle by running `./runInstaller` but I'm getting the following error.

```
root@kali:/opt/database# ./runInstaller
    
The user is root. Oracle Universal Installer cannot continue installation if the user is root.

root@kali:/opt/database#
```

Any help how to install Oracle in Kali Linux? or how to solve the above error?

Comment: What if you run it with a non-root user?

Comment: Have you read the Oracle documentation? And run DB as root is not a wise idea

Answer (score 2):

Oracle runs as a non-root user and the installer enforces this during the installation.  This protects you from all sorts of nastiness. (I just wish more applications followed this model.)

There is an installation guide which you should read before you install, and follow along as you do the installation.

Once you have completed the installation, you will need to run a script as root.  This will setup a few things that need to be done as root.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.

First create a normal user account.

Then run `su [your user acount]` in the terminal and run the installer.

Example

```
useradd -m -G wheel -s /bin/bash user
su user
```

First though check if the default admin group is sudo or wheel
if it is sudo and not wheel replace wheel with sudo in the first command. Just don't add your user to the group root and make sure to set a password.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's installer requires certain actions to be performed with root privileges, but does not and should not be invoked directly as the root user.  Instead, you run the installer using a regular, non-privileged user, and the installer prompts you to run certain actions as root in another session as needed.

See, for example, [Oracle's own installation instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/em.101/b12140/2_oui_using.htm). The URL is for an older release of their software but it's been this way for years so nothing is new.

A common practice is to create a shell user and group specifically for the Oracle installation.  That also has the advantage of keeping things like the environment settings local to a single user.

PS I love the irony of trying to do a root shell install on Kali :)